# What are the limitation on Solr schema while trying to use highlighting?

Tags: solr

I have solr with two field types.
I index a document with the same value on both fields:the value is "UNAVAILABLE DATA"
I then search for the term "UNAVAILABLE" with highlights on.
I found the document if I search for this term in field A or in Field B.
But the the field is only being highlighted in only one field. It turn out that:
Field A index the following terms: unavail, data
Field B index the following terms: unavailable, data

Does the highlighter expects both field types to generate the same terms?

Comment: What highlighter are you using? Have you specified both the fields for highlighting in you solrconfig.xml?

Comment: I use Solr 3.6 with the standard highlighter. Both fields are stored. I think I understand what Solr is donig. I just don't understant why. It looks like a bug.
Solr run the query analyzer on the first field. It then get some terms. It will then search the terms it got on other fields to see if they match. So if other fields has different analyzers it will not match.